# Centering text vertically in Bootstrap list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, html-table

So I am creating this website, With a top navigation menu, a left navigation menu and a main content container, all made with bootstrap. The problem is, I can't get the text in the top navigation menu and the left navigation menu to center vertically. I assume both have the same problem, so I will only show the code of the left menu:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 z-overview-left-menu">
        <ul class="z-left-list">
            <li class="z-left-list-item"><span class="z-test">One</span></li>
            <li class="z-left-list-item z-selected">Two</li>
            <li class="z-left-list-item">Three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 z-overview-main-menu">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.z-selected {
    background-color: rgb(255, 216, 0);
}

.z-left-list {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.z-left-list-item {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 7%;
    font-size: 150%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Simplified Jsfiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekfrwoz/)

So what am I doing wrong? I already tried adding `display: table` to the z-left-list and `display: table-cell` to the z-left-list-item classes.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: @alirezasafian jsfiddle provided.

Comment: If this is for a navigation menu, using Bootstrap, why are you not using the navbar classes?

Comment: I am new to bootstrap, I will have a look.

Comment: I posted an answer with a link to the Bootstrap navbar classes explanation.  Mind you, I am pretty sure navbar classes will do things like collapsing to the hamburger icon on smaller screens.  You want that functionality if you are going to be mobile friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
<div class="z-overview-left-menu">
    <ul class="z-left-list">
        <li class="z-left-list-item"><span class="z-test">One asdfasd fasd fasdf asdf asdf</span></li>
        <li class="z-left-list-item z-selected"><span>Two</span></li>
        <li class="z-left-list-item"><span>Three</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.z-left-list {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.z-left-list-item {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 150%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.z-left-list-item span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fekfrwoz/7/

Comment: sorry, your are working on on the left menu, I missundersuood it.
check it now
https://jsfiddle.net/fekfrwoz/7/

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you use the navbar classes.  See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).  This will make your code easier to maintain, and will take advantage of a lot of jscript coding done by Bootstrap to make those navbars work.  For example, on a mobile screen, navbars will collapse into the hamburger icon (the three stacked horizontal bars that give you a pulldown).  In my latest web app, I have two navbars (although located different from what you describe), and it works great.

Comment: I will look further into this

Comment: Also, if you are using Bootstrap, I am guessing you are trying to be mobile friendly (pretty much a requirement for web apps nowadays).  For that, I'd recommend against having a menu on the left.  You could have navbar fixed to the top with extra pulldowns, or a fixed navbar and one that scrolls with the page just below it, or two fixed navbars stacked over each other (a la CNN.com).  But you don't want to eat up your precious horizontal screen real state on a menu and force the user on a mobile to scroll sideways as well as up and down.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your list items will only have one line of text, you could always just add `line-height` to the `.z-left-list-item` class definition.

https://jsfiddle.net/fekfrwoz/1/

Comment: The problem with that is that my height is in percentages, and then that doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I didn't notice that in your question. I'll leave this here for future visitors, but the other answers should provide some alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the height of the .z-left-list-item and use padding on the top and the bottom of the li, like so:

```
padding: 35px 0;
```

Which would emulate them being in the center of the li?

Comment: I want it to be responsive, so when the screen height changes, the hardcoded values wouldn't be correct anymore